# dotnet build with GeneratePackageOnBuild and contentFiles

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project that I'm building with `dotnet build -c Release /p:Platform=x86 .\Foo.csproj`.
The `csproj` file is in SDK format and has this content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <AssemblyName>Foo</AssemblyName>
    <Company>Me</Company>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Version>4.12.5</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>4.12.5.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>4.12.5.0</FileVersion>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Bar.csproj">
      <!-- ... -->
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="FilesToCopy">
    <Content Include="..\dependent.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath=".\lib\net48\" PackageCopyToOutput="true" />
    <None Include="image.jpg" Pack="true" PackagePath=".\contentFiles\any\any\" PackageCopyToOutput="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="tex_cardboard.jpg">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths-&gt;WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This will generate a nuget package on build with the `image.jpg` in a `contentFiles\any\any` folder.

If I understand correctly, the the `.nuspec` file inside of the nuget package should contain:

```xml
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*" buildAction="Content" />
    </contentFiles>
```

But it does not.

How do I tell, in the `csproj` file, the image file to be included as content and not to be compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the NuSpec file inside your package will contain the `contentFiles` tag **unless** you define a custom `PackagePath` for your resources in the project file. It guess that this behavior applies to `.csproj` files, because the default path for content files is overwritten for that file and it is no longer detected as content file applying to NuGet conventions. From the `.csproj` [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) and [MS Build targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets):

> This property specifies the default location of where all the content files should go if PackagePath is not specified for them. The default value is "content;contentFiles".

> By default, everything gets added to the root of the content and contentFiles\any<target_framework> folder within a package and preserves the relative folder structure, unless you specify a package path [...]

Although it is explcitly stated that you can use the `PackagePath` on a lot of content types with different build actions, there is no mention that this results in a different NuSpec file, but in practice it does.

> Apart from Content items, the  and  metadata can also be set on files with a build action of Compile, EmbeddedResource, ApplicationDefinition, Page, Resource, SplashScreen, DesignData, DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreateableTypes, CodeAnalysisDictionary, AndroidAsset, AndroidResource, BundleResource or None. [...]

In your `csproj` file, tags like `None` and `Content` determine the build action and therefore whether your image file is embedded, copied to the output folder or anything else. However, apart from the original issue, setting `Pack="true"` is enough to automatically include it in the `contenFiles\any\<Target framework moniker>` folder in your package. Setting `PackageCopyToOutput="true"` will copy it to the consuming project's output directory.

Comment: Thank you for the info and reference, as soon as I fix it I'll accept the answer! Have a good one!